# getting all records if $in array if empty, mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to use $in operator on mongodb, I have an array, but I want if array is empty I should get all records:

```
db.bios.find( { contribs: { $in: [ "ALGOL", "Lisp" ]} } )
```

How can I do that. Please help.

Comment: please provide sample data

Answer (score 0):

You would build the query dynamically, like

```
let query={};

if (queryArray.length > 0) {
  query.contribs = queryArray;
}

db.bios.find(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

the best option is you just create query dynamically same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69112699/6566877).

but in any case if you want to go with database query then you can do with below way.

- `$expr` - for check that is input array is empty or not. if not empty then pass array else return all.
- `$size` - to get size of input array

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $cond: {
      if: {
        $size: [
          [
            "ALGOL"
          ]
        ]
      },
      then: {
        $in: [
          "$contribs",
          [
            "ALGOL"
          ]
        ]
      },
      else: {}
    }
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pD5P7-56Oxi)