# MongoDB Aggregate conditional match criteria

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am looking to set up a series of filter options on the ui and then have the backend perform the search due to the amount of data that could come back with no filters. Not all filter criteria may be present in each search case. With $and, if one of the conditions is not present, nothing returns, with $or, if only 1 resolves to true, it can end up returning all documents.

Here's along the lines of what I've tried:

```
        await Visit.aggregate()
            .match(
                {
                    $and: [
                        {client: clientId},
                        {$or: [
                        {user: userId},
                        {visitStart: {$gte: new Date(isStart)}},
                        {visitEnd: {$lte: new Date(isEnd)}}
                        ]}
                    ]
                }
                )
            .sort({ date: 'asc'})
            .exec((err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    res.send(err);
                } else {
                    res.json(result);
                }
            });
```

This at least only returns documents relevant to the main criteria, the client. But if any of the 3 conditional criteria resolves to true then it will return more than the requested search. For example, if I specify a userId, a start date, and an end date, as long as any document matches before the end date (even if it does not meet the other 2 criteria) it gets returned in the results. I'm sure there has to be a clean way to make such a conditional search, any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/69112699/2282634

Comment: @Joe interesting, since I'm basing the queries on what 'filter' options are being passed in the body, I've set it up similar to that answer (just not clean or simple) with a lot of if() statements directing towards the eventual conditions, and using .find() from there. works, but I was hoping there was a cleaner method in mongo